# Spy on coffee-script constructor in sinon

Tags: javascript, testing, coffeescript, sinon, chai

I'm attempting to verify that a coffee-script constructor throws an exception (using sinon and sinon-chai).

```
class Animal
  constructor: ->
    throw "exception"

class Dog extends Animal
```

How do I correctly create a spy to verify that instantiating Dog throws an exception?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use an anonymous function to create your object inside, so you can pass it the `expects`. No sinon needed so far.

```
expect(-> new Animal()).to.throw(/message/)
```

Beware, that the regexp in chai's `throw` always passes if you throw a simple string. It only works properly if you throw an Error object. Anyway it's always better to throw real errors.

```
class Animal
  constructor: ->
    throw new Error('message') # only this will assert the regexp above
```

Hope this helps.